# Redux request statuses. Reduce boilerplate

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I am using Redux with react and redux-thunk as a middleware.

When I make http requests I have to dispatch three actions in my thunks. 
I will use my auth example.

here are my actions:

```
export const loginSuccess = () => ({
  type: AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
})

export const loginFailure = (errorMessage) => ({
  type: AUTH_LOGIN_FAILURE,
  errorMessage,
})

export const loginRequest = () => ({
  type: AUTH_LOGIN_REQUEST,
})
```

and here is the thunk which combines above three actions:

```
export const login = (credentials) => dispatch => {
  dispatch(loginRequest())
  const options = {
    method: 'post',
    url: `${ENDPOINT_LOGIN}?username=${credentials.username}&password=${credentials.password}`,
  }
  axiosInstance(options)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch(loginSuccess())
      dispatch(loadUser(response.data)) // I have separate action for user and separate reducer.
      window.localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY, response.data.token)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return dispatch(loginFailure(error))
    })
}
```

And here is my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  pending: false,
  error: false,
  errorMessage: null,
}

export const loginReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        pending: false,
        error: false,
        errorMessage: null,
      }
    case AUTH_LOGIN_FAILURE:
      const { errorMessage } = action
      return {
        ...state,
        pending: false,
        error: true,
        errorMessage,
      }
    case AUTH_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {
        ...state,
        pending: true,
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I have to do almost exact same things when I am sending another request, for example in case of logout. I feel like I am repeating myself a lot and there must be a better way.

I need to know what is the best practice to handle this issue.

Any other corrections and recommendations will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for "ready to use" solution take a look at:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk
- https://redux-resource.js.org/ (but it is written with js (not TS), and no @types definition for this library)

If you are looking for a custom solution you can create a few factories:

- factory for reducer
- factory for three actions
- factory for thunk

```js
const actions = createActions('My request name');
const reducer = createReducer(actions);
...
const thunk = createThunk(config);
```

or even you can combine them:

```js
const { actions, reducer, thunk } = createRequestState('Name...', config);
```

... but this is just an idea.